# js-datepicker - date picker is not defined

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to get a date picker working using the following external library and example - https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker

I'm getting the errors:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'[Learn More]  datepicker.css:1
ReferenceError: Datepicker is not defined[Learn More]  index.html:1:1
```

The relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="datepicker.css"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="datePick" onclick="Datepicker('#datePick')"> 
    <script src="datepicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `css` and `js` file are both in the same folder as my `html` file.

Comment: You don't reference a CSS file with script tags `<script src="datepicker.css"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one:

```
<script src="datepicker.css"></script>
```

should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css">
```

Then you should put inside a script tag, the initialization instead of 'onClick':

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    const picker = datepicker('#datePick');
</script>
```

For minimal aproach. You can check with a debugger if the file `datepicker.js` is loaded, and if not, use a CDN (in the beggining) and then when all works,change it for your local `datepicker.js` in your own folder.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the `ReferenceError` in my original post, I'll see if I can get a CDN to test.

Comment: Of course, you can use: <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-datepicker"></script> instead of: <script src="datepicker.js"></script>

Comment: I'm still getting the error when using the CDN. I have the `<script>` tags immediately after the `<input>` tag - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<script src="datepicker.css"></script>` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css">`. Its a CSS stylesheet, not a JS source file.

Answer (score 0):

Use lowercase in onClick function:

```
 <input type="text" id="datePick" onclick="datepicker('#datePick')">
```

Works on this example (with proper loaded .js and .css):
https://jsfiddle.net/wg2LqL33/